# Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)?

Tags: regex, string, perl, matching

I've looked at the other answers regarding this and am still not sure why I am getting this issue: **Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)**

```
my $curr = 0;
my (@up_intf, @nh_ID);
my $line = "";
for (my $index = 0; $index < length(@lines); $index++) {
       $line = $lines[$index];
       print("The line is: $line");
       if (($line =~ /^Group:/i)) {
          while (1) {
             if (($line =~ /^Uptime:/i)) { last; }
             else {
               $index++;
               $line = $lines[$index];
               if (($line =~ /^Downstream/i)) {
                  $index++;
                  $line = $lines[$index];
                  print($line);
                  $up_intf[$curr] = $line;
               }
               if (($line =~ /^Next-hop/i)) {
                  $nh_ID[$curr] = substr($line, 13, ((length($line) - 13)));
                  print($line);
                  $curr++;
               }
              }
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you think `$index < length(@lines)` does? See also [Loopy Validation](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Loopy-Validation.aspx) ... Long story short, lose that `while(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop should be:

```
for (my $index = 0; $index < $#lines; $index++) {
```

There is a lot of other things wrong, but that's a starting point.

`$#lines` gives the last index of `@lines` whereas `scalar @lines` gives the number of elements in `@lines`. [`length @lines`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) does not do what you think it does.

Looking at your loop:

```
           if (($line =~ /^Downstream/i)) {
              $index++;
              $line = $lines[$index];
              print($line);
              $up_intf[$curr] = $line;
           }
```

What if the last line matches `/^Downstream/i`? You then assign an undefined value to `$line` and go on to:

```
          if (($line =~ /^Next-hop/i)) {
              $nh_ID[$curr] = substr($line, 13, ((length($line) - 13)));
              print($line);
              $curr++;
           }
```

where you would get the warning.

The way you are doing the processing is, for lack of a better term, whacky.

Comment: Better written as `for my $i ( 0..$#lines ) {` ;)

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to fix one thing at a time.